# jQuery loop with localStorage variable not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Every time you load the page or click the #desc div, the content should change to a different array item. There will be more, that's why there's Math.random().

Problem is, the loop that should generate a different number every time isn't working.

EDIT: Thanks for all responses, changing === to == helped ;)

```
var descs = [
    "^that's me",
    "make the web great again"
];

function changeDesc() {
    var randNum = Math.abs(Math.round(Math.random()*descs.length-1));
    if (randNum == localStorage.getItem("usedDescs")) {
        changeDesc();
    }
    else {
        localStorage.setItem("usedDescs", randNum);
        $("#desc").html(descs[localStorage.getItem("usedDescs")]);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    changeDesc();
    $("#desc").click(function() {
        changeDesc();
    });
});
```

Comment: i not sure, but seems for concrete this `descs` - `randNum` always `0`

Comment: Tested - randNum is 0 or 1, not the problem...

Comment: damn :-) you use `Math.round`, and not ceil, or floor

Comment: try `localStorage.set/getItem()` instead of `localStorage.xxx`

Comment: Can you please comment the syntax for that?

Comment: @Vaclav: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you compare the integer `randNum` with the string `localStorage.usedDesc`

Do this and see for yourself:

`console.log(typeof localStorage.usedDescs)`

`console.log(typeof randNum)`

Using `localStorage.set/getItem()` is the 'correct' way to do it but what you have written is valid as well.

Answer (score 0):

Localstorage values are always strings, no matter the input. So the comparison between randNum and localStorage.usedDescs will always fail.